# How do I convert an image to a http/https url for python?

Tags: url, https, discord.py, python-imaging-library

I've used pillow to generate an image combining two random images, such that a new image is generated each the code is ran, but i want the image to be a http/https url since it needs to be embedded in discord, which only supports http/https url's.

Comment: Attach file to the message and use that url. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Using [discord.File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=discord%20file#discord.File) and attachement-url you will be able to send your generated images through an embed

You can try the following code:

```py
    @commands.command(name="image")
    async def _image(self, ctx):
        image = Image.new("RGBA", size=(500, 500), color=(0, 0, 0))
        with BytesIO() as img_bin:
            image.save(img_bin, "PNG")
            img_bin.seek(0)
            file = discord.File(img_bin, filename="yourImage.png") 

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Embed", description="description")
        embed.set_image(url="attachment://yourImage.png")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://yourImage.png")

        await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)
```

Comment: I tried that but when I run the code the embed doesn't show the image.

Comment: Did you edited the code ? I tested the code and it shows two black square in an embed.